# How to position image label right on top of textbox

Tags: html, css

Using the following css

```
 .prenom { width: 200px;    background-image: url('/Images/Prénom.jpg') ;background-repeat: no-repeat;display: block;background-position: left top;}
```

I get this

[image]

I want this

[image]

where the background image would be on top and OUTSIDE of the textbox

Do I need to create a different object for my image or can i set a css property to have a padding on top for the textbox

Thanks

Comment: Why exactly was this tagged classic ASP??!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to attach it to different object in your HTML. The advantage is that you probably get less problems to make a consistent experience across browsers.

Comment: if it's for an intranet only running on chrome.. Would you answer still be the same ?

Comment: Well, that of course changing my perspective a bit. But still messing around with negative margins or absolute positionings is normally not worth the trouble. Then the answer provided by Josh is the better option. :)

Answer (score 1):

You looking for something like this?

HTML

```
<div>
    <form>
        <label for="text1">Random Text</label>
        <input type="text" name="text1" />   
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS

```
label{
    display:block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xero1212/u56qF/5/

Comment: The label is from an image, the client is using some strange fonts, so we created some img labels.

Comment: So the text box is really an image and not a text box?

Comment: <div>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.Prenom, new {autocomplete ="off", @class="prenom"})
                        </div>

Comment: which renders to 
  <div>
                            <input autocomplete="off" class="prenom" data-val="true" data-val-required="Le prénom est requis" id="Prenom" name="Prenom" type="text" value="" />
                        </div>

Comment: Okay, so then is the actual text "Prenom" created within the image? Because the way you just described it makes me think that the input is an image with your word "Prenom" included in it? Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
.prenom { width: 200px;
display: block;
position:relative
}
.prenom:after{
content:url('/Images/Prénom.jpg');
display:block;
position:relative;
top: -30px;
left:0;
}
```

-30px can be change to adjust the image

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
.prenom { 
   width: 200px;    
   display: block;
   background:url('/Images/Prénom.jpg') 0 -10px no-repeat;
 }
```

The value `-10px` can be modified to suit your requirement.